# How do I find the generalised answer for the trace and determinant of the given linear operator?

Tags: abstract-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider the linear operator of left multiplication by an $m \times m$ matrix $A$ on the space $F^{m \times m}$ of all $m \times m$ matrices. Determine the trace and the determinant of this operator.

Attempt : Consider a basis $B = \{v_1, v_2,\dots, v_n\}, \\AB = \{Av_1, Av_2, \dots, Av_n\}$

After this I'm doubtful if my working is right, I was thinking that these elements would form an $n^2 \times n^2$ matrix with the $n \times n$ matrix $A$ in each of the diagonal elements.
But I also don't really see if that would be mathematically right, and we don't really use the fact that the matrix is over the space $F^{m \times m}$.

Comment: Connected : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3561560/305862.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us take the following basis :

$$E_1=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}, \ E_2=\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}, \ E_3=\pmatrix{0&0\\1&0}, \ E_4=\pmatrix{0&0\\0&1}\tag{1}$$

with

$$A:=\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}=aE_1+bE_2+cE_3+dE_4$$

One can verify that :

$$AE_1=\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}\pmatrix{1&0\\c&0}=\pmatrix{a&0\\c&0}=aE_1+cE_3$$

In the same way :

$$AE_2=aE_2+cE_4, \ AE_3=bE_1+dE_3, \ AE_4=bE_2+dE_4$$

Whence the following matrix (with respect to basis (1)) for the operator : $\tilde{A} : M \mapsto AM$ :

$$\tilde{A}:=\left(\begin{array}{cc|cc} a&0&b&0\\0&a&0&b\\ \hline c&0&d&0\\0&c&0&d\end{array}\right)=\pmatrix{aI_2&bI_2\\cI_2&dI_2}\tag{2}$$

One can verify that

$$\operatorname{Trace}(\tilde{A})=2 \operatorname{Trace}(A)$$

$$\det(\tilde{A})=(ad-bc)^2=(\det(A))^2$$

Important remark : In fact, (2) can be expressed under the form :

$$\tilde{A}=A \otimes I_2$$

where $\otimes$ denotes the Kronecker product operator and $I_n$ the identity matrix of order $n$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) where you will find in particular (paragraph n°7) the formula $\det(A \otimes B)=\det(A)^m \det(B)^n$ if $A$ is an $m \times m$ matrix and $B$ is an $n \times n$ matrix.

Regarding the trace, we have :

$$\operatorname{Trace}(A \otimes B)=\operatorname{Trace}(A)\operatorname{Trace}(B).$$

(a reference [here](https://www.statlect.com/matrix-algebra/Kronecker-product-properties)).

What we have done can be generalized almost instantly.

Comment: For the answer here, I understand it but I don't see how $AE_1 = aE_1 + bE_3$. Shouldn't it be $aE_1 + cE_3$?

Comment: Of course, I correct it at once.

Comment: I have added the general formula for the trace of a Kronecker product.